# How to use \r\n stored in a custom setting field

Tags: apex, csv

I'm trying to setup custom settings for my CSV Writer/Reader.

Therefore I'd like to enable customized linebreaks.
But i'm just not able to create a new line, '\r\n' is just printed into my string.

How to unescape it? I tried things like

```
newLine.replace('\\\\','\\');     // no result
newLine.replace('\\','');         // result: rn

newLine.countMatches('\\');       // returns: 2
newLine.splitByCharacterType();   // returns: (\, r, \, n)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escapes are for source code, not normal field data.

This means that given the following value in a field:

```
\r\n
```

The actual value in terms of source code would be:

```
\\r\\n
```

You could consider the contents of the string to be already escaped, which means you have to unescape them, like this:

```
newLine.replace('\\r','\r').replace('\\n','\n');
```

For sake of completeness, I'd probably also recommend adding `\t` as well (for tab-separated value files).